# Problema en el responsive y actualizacion de dato en el Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Es un problema que tengo en lo que es el responsive de datatable
este es un codigo simple

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$('#example2').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "responsive": true,
});


if ($("#example2 .btn").length) {
    $("#example2").on("click", ".btn", function () {
        let this_btn = $(this);
        
        let row = this_btn.closest("tr")[0];
        
        $(row).find("ul li").html('....')

    })
}
```

})

lo cual agrego contenido al li.
Se sabe que datatable si no quepa todas las columnas este agrega un signo mas a la izquierda de cada fila y muestra las columnas que no quepan

bueno cuando hago click en el boton cuando todas las columnas quepan me agrega el contenido al li pero si abro el inspecionaddor de elemento y lo hago pequeño hasta el punto que la columnna que contiene la lista y el boton se oculten y solo se muestren cuando de click en el boton + de datatable
cuando hago esto el contenido del li que puse cuando di click y todas las columnas se mostraban ya no esta
me podrian ayudar

Por ejemplo aqui di click en el primer boton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui hago responsive y habro la columna que no quepo y el contenido ya no esta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]